# System.StackOverflowException in windows dll

Tags: c#, regex, wpf

```
public static void AlphabeticPasting(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.DataObject.GetDataPresent(typeof(string)))
    {
        var text = e.DataObject.GetData(typeof(string)) as string;
        if (!Regex.IsMatch(text, (Properties.Resources.Alpha)))
        {
            //replace and recopy
            var trimmed = Regex.Replace(text,Properties.Resources.AlphaPasting, string.Empty);
            e.CancelCommand();
            Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Text, trimmed);
            ApplicationCommands.Paste.Execute(trimmed, e.Source as FrameworkElement);

        }
    }
}
```

I want to restrict numeric part to paste in text box ,
I'm calling this method inside the DataObject.Pasting property of textbox ,Properties.Resources.Alphabet and Properties.Resources.AlphabetPasting are the regex part and i mentioned regex equation in resource file.

```
Alpha = ^[[A-Za-z-~`!@#$%^&*()_+=|{}':;.,<>/\\]?]*$ and AlphaPsting = [^[A-Za-z-~`!@#$%^&*()_+=|{}':;.,<>/\\]?]+
```

and i need to take the regex equation from resource file only.

i'm getting System.StackOverFlowException if i try to past the anything in text box.Please help me out to solve this.

Comment: If you are handling the event for alphabeticPasting, is it not just invoked again when you do the ApplicationCommand.Paste.Execute?  That might cause it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appears that the entire method is called as the result of a Paste event.  If this is not the case, then just ignore this answer.  ApplicationCommands.Paste.Execute() is going to trigger the event, putting your code into an endless loop.

Instead of using ApplicationCommands.Paste.Execute(), try casting the sender object as a TextBox and then just set the Text property accordingly.  To make it work, you'll probably have to track more information (cursor position, length, etc.), but you shouldn't be stuck in a loop.